# AngularJS: From $location to $route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Hey guys I changed my angular app to work with the ui.router directive, but I need to change the code I already had made with $location, Changed everything already but this part of the code,

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$location,checkLogin,User){
    $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart",function(event,next,current){
        checkLogin.check(function(response){
            if (response) {
                var nextUrl = next.$$route.orginalPath

                if (nextUrl == '/login' || nextUrl == '/') {
                    $location.path('panel');
                }
                $rootScope.isLogged =true;
            }else{
                    $rootScope.isLogged =false;
                    $location.path('login');

                }
        });
    });
});
```

I need to transform the next.$$route.orginalPath from $location
to its $state alternative? 
Sorry for bad english, long story short I need to update my code from $location to $state

Answer (score 0):

$state.go('panel', {'parameter_name': parameter_value});

The first parameter 'panel' is the $stateProvider.state route name (not the url state) and the second parameter are the route paremeters if they have been defined.

I can see that you are validating if the user has an active session each time he enters to the route, this is not a good practice. You should validate user session on your api rest service each time he requests to the server (this is possible using an angular http interceptor. Using interceptors allows you to do something at sending or at receiving the request.

here a demo: http://i.prntscr.com/IWszLQxwQ9ic09sgyJRpvQ.png).

Comment: Yes I am doing it in the server side too, this is for a double validation.